# How to install CM over an existing non CDH Cluster

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

Is it possible to install CM over an existing non CDH cluster?

For example, I have manually installed Hadoop and other services to my VMs.

Can I install CM and force it to manage my cluster?

Answer (score 0):

It is doubtful you could do this since CM expects either parcels or CDH packages installed with Hadoop.  If you really wanted to try to do this, it would be easier to install CM + CDH using packages then overwrite the specific artifacts in the package but this could be very tedious.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to install Cloudera Manager on an non CDH Cluster. One of the reasons is Cloudera expects the installation to be carried out using the CDH packages or using the CDH parcels. Even CDH Packages and CDH parcels can't coexist. Other reason is that the jars bundled by Cloudera are different from the jars available in the native distributions of the software components such as Hive etc. So, It is not going to work.

Don't waste time attempting it.